# How to build advanced boxplots from datasets which columns contain only numbers?

Tags: r

I have got a fold-change dataset and I simply would like to plot something like this:

[image]

The problem is that I have only numbers in my columns and when I use a boxplot() function I can plot only boxes but not dots, jitter, etc.

I use this code to build a df and then proceed to a boxplot

```
A <- c(-1, 25, 3, 4, 50)
B <- c(23, -41, 32, 68, 26)
C <- c(63, 71, 22, -8, 2)
D <- c(16, -49, 2, 56, 6)
df <- data.frame(A, B, C, D)
print (df)
boxplot(df)
```

How can I plot something that looks like the above picture? Thanks

Comment: You want `ggplot2`, specifically the `geom_boxplot` and `geom_dotplot` functions. Check out the [cheat sheet](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/main/data-visualization.pdf) (warning: PDF download) to see the full functionality of the package.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that I don't have ```geom``` data - if you check the dataset I have proposed - there is no ```"y"``` data, I have only 4 columns (A,B,C,D) and rows with numbers. It is ok for default boxplot() while I cannot add geom, can you specify what should the ggplot2 script look like for the above-mentioned dataset? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>To coerce your data into a form interpretable by `ggplot2`, you can use the `gather` function from `tidyr`.</strike>

`gather` has been superseded by `pivot_longer`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(A = c(-1, 25, 3, 4, 50),
             B = c(23, -41, 32, 68, 26),
             C = c(63, 71, 22, -8, 2),
             D = c(16, -49, 2, 56, 6))

tidyr::pivot_longer(data = df, cols = c(A,B,C,D)) |>
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = name, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]